# Open CL Kernel - every workitem overwrites global memory?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, histogram

I'm trying to write a kernel to get the character frequencies of a string.

First, here is the code I have for kernel right now:

```
_kernel void readParallel(__global char * indata, __global int * outdata)
{
        int startId = get_global_id(0) * 8;
        int maxId = startId + 7;

        for (int i = startId; i < maxId; i++)
        {
            ++outdata[indata[i]];
        }
 }
```

The variable `inData` holds the string in the global memory, and `outdata` is an array of 256 `int` values in the global memory. Every workitem reads 8 symbols from the string and should increase the appropriate ASCII-code in the array. The code compiles and executes, but `outdata` contains less occurrences overall than the number of characters in `inData`. I think the problem is that workitems overwrites the global memory. It would be nice if you can give me some tips to solve this.

By the way,. I am a rookie in OpenCL ;-) and, yes, I looked for solutions in other questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the effects of your uses of global memory not being **atomic** ([C++-oriented description of what those are](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) or [another description by the Intel TBB folks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Atomic_Operations.html)). What happens, chronologically, is:

> Some workgroup "thread" loads `outData[123]` into some register `r1`
>
> ... lots of work, reading and writing, happens, including on
>   `outData[123]`...
>
> The same workgroup "thread" increments `r1`
>
> ... lots of work, reading and writing, happens, including on
>   `outData[123]`...
>
> The same workgroup "thread" writes `r1` to `outData[123]`

So, the value written to `outData[123]` "throws away" the updates during the time period between the read and the write (I'm ignoring the possibility of parallel writes corrupting each other rather than one of them winning out).

What you need to do is either:

- Use **atomic operations** - the least amount of modifications to your code, but very inefficient, since it serializes your work to a great extent, or
- Use **work-item-specific,  warp-specific and/or work-group-specific partial results**, which require less/cheaper synchronization, and combine them eventually after having done a lot of work on them.

---

On an unrelated note, and as @huseyintugrulbuyukisik correctly points out, your code uses signed `char` values to index the array. To fix that, do one of the following:

- reinterpret those `char`'s as `unsigned chars` for array indices (and reinterpret back when reading the array.
- upcast the char values to a larger integral type and add 128 to get an offset into the `outArray`.
- Define your kernel to only support [ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) characters (no higher than 127), in which case you can ignore this issue (although that will be a potential crasher if you get invalid input.
- If you only care about the frequency of [*printable* characters](http://web.itu.edu.tr/sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html) (but can also have non-printing characters in the input), you could perform a run-time check before counting a character.

Comment: also char could be negative and underflow the input array for c>127. unsigned char is working for me

Comment: Using unsigned char and atomic operations did it for me. Thank you.

Comment: @j_ice: You express your gratitude for a good answer answers by upvoting it; and if it resolved your problem - you mark it as accepted. If not, it's useful for others to explain what's missing/not right about it, in a comment.