# Getting an unexpected value in global device memory when multiple threads write to it

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, race-condition, atomic

Here is problem with cuda threads , memory magament, it returns single threads result "100" but would expect 9 threads result "900".

```
#indudel <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <helper_functions.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>


__global__ 
void test(int in1,int*ptr){
    int e = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
       e++;
    }

    *ptr +=e;

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int devID = 0;


    cudaError_t error;
    error = cudaGetDevice(&devID);


    if (error == cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("GPU Device fine\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("GPU Device problem, aborting");
        abort();
    }


    int* d_A;
    cudaMalloc(&d_A, sizeof(int));

    int res=0;

    //cudaMemcpy(d_A, &res, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    test <<<3, 3 >>>(0,d_A);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(&res, d_A, sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("res is : %i",res);

     Sleep(10000);
     return 0;
}
```

It returns:
GPU Device fine\n
res is : 100

Would expect it to return higher number because 3x3(blocks,threads), insted of just one threads result?
What is done wrong and where does the numbers get lost?

Comment: You probably have a race condition on writing to `*ptr`. Use atomic addition with `atomicAdd` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write your sum in this way to global memory.
You have to use an [atomic function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) to ensure that the store is atomic.

In general, when having multiple device threads writing into the same values on global memory, you have to use either [atomic functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) :

> float atomicAdd(float* address, float val);
>   double atomicAdd(double*
>   address, double val);
>
> reads the 32-bit or 64-bit word old located at the address address in
>   global or shared memory, computes (old + val), and stores the result
>   back to memory at the same address. These three operations are
>   performed in one atomic transaction. The function returns old.

or [thread synchronization](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#synchronization-instruction) :

> Throughput for __syncthreads() is 16 operations per clock cycle for
>   devices of compute capability 2.x, 128 operations per clock cycle for
>   devices of compute capability 3.x, 32 operations per clock cycle for
>   devices of compute capability 6.0 and 64 operations per clock cycle
>   for devices of compute capability 5.x, 6.1 and 6.2.
>
> Note that __syncthreads() can impact performance by forcing the
>   multiprocessor to idle as detailed in Device Memory Accesses.

Answer (score 1):

(adapting another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42585288/1593077) of mine:)

You are experiencing the effects of the increment operator not being atomic. ([C++-oriented description of what that means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42585288/1593077)). What's happening, chronologically, is the following sequence of events (not necessarily in the same order of threads though):

> ...(other work)...
>
> block 0 thread 0 issues a LOAD instruction with address ptr into register r
>   block 0 thread 1 issues a LOAD instruction with address ptr into register r
>   ...
>   block 2 thread 0 issues a LOAD instruction with address ptr into register r
>
> block 0 thread 0 completes the LOAD, now having 0 in register r
>   ...
>   block 2 thread 2 completes the LOAD, now having 0 in register r
>
> block 0 thread 0 adds 100 to r
>   ...
>   block 2 thread 2 adds 100 to r
>
> block 0 thread 0 issues a STORE instruction from register r to address ptr 
>   ...
>   block 2 thread 2 issues a STORE instruction from register r to address ptr

Thus every thread sees the initial value of `*ptr`, which is 0; adds 100; and stores 0+100=100 back. The order of the stores doesn't matter here as long as all of the threads try to store the same false value.

What you need to do is either:

- Use **atomic operations** - the least amount of modifications to your code, but very inefficient, since it serializes your work to a great extent, or
- Use a **block-level reduction primitive**. This will ensure some partial ordering of the computational activity vis-a-vis shared block memory - using `__syncthreads()` or other mechanisms. Thus it might first have each thread add its own two elements up; then synchronize block threads; then have less threads add up pairs of pair-sums and so on. Here's an [nVIDIA blog post](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/) on implementing fast reductions on their more modern GPU architectures.

**block-local or  warp-local and/or work-group-specific partial results**, which require less/cheaper synchronization, and combine them eventually after having done a lot of work on them.